# how to convert a string to a function in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I need to apply some functions to a map of values.
The functions are around 900 function in the worst case so i created them as records in a database and load them at once to a map.This way i may create an admin page to manage all the conversion formulas ... one day...

Now I have them like this

```
conversion=%{"0":"Tools.Myfunc1/1","1":"Tools.Myfunc2/1",etc...}
```

then I need to apply/execute them in a map statement.

The problem is that they are as strings and i get this error

`|>Stream.zip(conversion)
 |>Enum.map( fn {rawValue, formula} -> convertUsing(rawValue,formula) end)`

expected a function, got "myModule.Myfunc/1"

```
def convertUsing(value,formula) do
        {h,form}=formula
            value
            |>ieee
            |>form.()
     end
```

Comment: Do they all have an arity of 1 or could that change? Also, it looks like when you call the function in `convertUsing` you are expecting an arity of 0 which means no arguments.

Comment: arity of 1 always. If i just pass a &myFunc1/1 in the ConvertUsing , it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could prepend a `&` and then use `Code.eval_string/1` to evaluate the contents of the string. This will give you the desired captured function:

```
defmodule Conversion do
  def convert_using(value, conversions) do
    conversions
    |> Enum.map(&string_to_fun/1)
    |> Enum.reduce(value, &apply(&1, [&2]))
  end

  defp string_to_fun(str) do
    {fun, _} = Code.eval_string("&#{str}")
    fun
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```
defmodule Tools do
  def piratize(str), do: "#{str} arr!"
  def upcase(str), do: String.upcase(str)
end

"Hello, world!"
|> Conversion.convert_using(["Tools.piratize/1", "Tools.upcase/1"])
|> IO.puts

# HELLO, WORLD! ARR!
```

You might want to restrict the allowed functions to a certain module that contains only trivial conversions or so, otherwise you might introduce some security risk. For example:

```
defp string_to_fun(str) do
  {fun, _} = Code.eval_string("&Tools.#{str}")
  fun
end
```

And then just store `"upcase/1"` and so on in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Kernal.apply](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3) combined with [String.to_atom](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_atom/1) help you? This would require you to have the function implemented in the module called by `apply`.

`apply(<Module Name>, <:string_converted_to_atom>, [<args>])`